Install Artifact Registry Python package from Dockerfile with Cloud Build
I have a python package located in my Artifact Registry repository.
My Dataflow Flex Template is packaged within a Docker image with the following command:
gcloud builds submit --tag $CONTAINER_IMAGE .

Since developers are constantly changing the source code of the pipeline, this command is often run from their computers to rebuild the image.
Here is my Dockerfile:
FROM gcr.io/dataflow-templates-base/python311-template-launcher-base

ARG WORKDIR=/template
RUN mkdir -p ${WORKDIR}
WORKDIR ${WORKDIR}

ENV PYTHONPATH ${WORKDIR}
ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_SETUP_FILE="${WORKDIR}/setup.py"
ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_PY_FILE="${WORKDIR}/main.py"

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -U pip && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir -U keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -U --index-url=https://europe-west9-python.pkg.dev/sample-project/python-repo/ mypackage

COPY . ${WORKDIR}/
    
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/google/dataflow/python_template_launcher"]

I get the following error:
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mypackage
error building image: error building stage: failed to execute command: waiting for process to exit: exit status 1

I guess the Cloud Build process doesn't have the access rights. I'm a bit confused on how to get them from a Dockerfile.
An article I found was mentionning the use of a Service Account key file read by the Docker process, but I would like to avoid that. Could I use the Service Account impersonation feature?

I think this is an interesting question. Unfortunately, I've not used Artifact Registry for anything other than container images. I think you want to keep your containerfile portable so that you can build on Cloud Build and anywhere. For this reason, I think (!?) the best solution will be to mount a key and export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS. That said, you can't piggyback the e.g. Cloud Build credentials and turn these into the credentials to mount. So, I think you'll want to use Secret Manager to hold a distinct key and mount that.

Solution was simpler than expected. pip had trouble finding the package because of misuse of the package locations flags which are --index-url and --extra-url. I used the former whereas I should have used the latter.
I need --extra-url to point to my Artifact Registry repository to find my package and --index-url to point to the default PyPI to find dependencies needed by my package.
In short, here's what I just added to my Dockerfile:
RUN pip install keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth
RUN pip install --extra-index-url https://europe-west9-python.pkg.dev/sample-project/python-repo/simple/ mypackage==0.3.0


Nice! Thanks for sharing this.

Please check this example: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/main/dataflow/flex-templates/pipeline_with_dependencies/Dockerfile
You need to make sure mypackage is in your container.

I'm not sure to understand the link with this solution and my isssue. Like you said, I need to make sure my package in my container before running pip install .. But that's the whole problem, I have trouble accessing to Artifact Registry, so I can't install it.
Unless you are suggesting to manually install the package (copying it from my sites-packages folder). In that case I don't find this solution very clean.

COPY my_package my_package you can just do this.

I don't understand. Where is my_package coming from? The package I'm using has been installed with pip install and is from Artifact Registry. It is not located in my local repository so I can't just copy it.

I see. pip install --no-cache-dir -U --index-url=https://europe-west9-python.pkg.dev/sample-project/python-repo/ mypackage : does this work locally?

Yes, it does. To make it work locally, I had to do pip install keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth. I also had to add the Artifact Registry repository configuration to my Python project by following the instructions of this command: gcloud artifacts print-settings python \     --project=sample-project \     --repository=python-repo \     --location=europe-west9
